# Scale every page preserving links

Tags: pdf, transformation

I have a document that I want to use for print and ebook (pdf). I don't what to check line-breaks and pagination twice, so I was planning to use two slightly different configuration of the `geometry` package to have the same text block width and height for both outputs (the text block should be the same but the paper different).

This approach leaves to big margins in the ebook output because the aspect ratio of the paper and the ebook reader are differerent. I had the crazy idea that it may be possible to scale the pdf for the print version with different scales in horizontal and vertical (I know this will distort the fonts and the images).

It is possible to do this using `pdfpages` package's option `fitpaper`. But as far as I know, `pdfpages` doesn't preserve the links. So, the question is: Is there a way to scale every page, with different scale factor for horizontal and vertical, at run time?

(Note: I am using XeLaTeX, but solutions with LuaLaTeX are also wellcome.)

Comment: Is the issue more "size" or "aspect ratio"? Meaning: for the eBook you can probably have close to zero margin. Differing aspect ratio will get you only too-large margins for one of horizontal or vertical, the other can be scaled away (e.g. with the [blowup](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/blowup?lang=en) package). (I don't think scaling horizontally and vertically with different factors will result in something that looks nice; I would much rather have large margins for one of the two dimensions.)

Comment: @WillieWong: You are right that I can work on margins and that the deformation is not a good idea. I was asking just to see if the engines are capable of doing that.

Comment: First, find out the current sizes of \the\textheight and \the\textwidth.  So long as you preserve those values, the line-breaks and pagination should remain unchanged.